# A Bug Crawls Along a Square

Tags: calculus, recreational-mathematics

A wire of length $4$ is bent into a square. At time $t = 0$, a bug starts crawling from the corner of the square to an adjacent corner, and continues traveling along the rest of the square until it reaches its original starting point at $t = 1$ (the bug's speed is constant). Given that the center of the square is $O$, the bug's starting point is $A$, and the bug's location at time $t$ is $B$, how much is the measure of $\angle AOB$ changing at time $t=0.3$? Angle measures are in radians.

Comment: Hint: at time $0.3$ the bug is on its second side of the square.  Draw a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bit physics. $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega=\dfrac{v_\perp}{r}$.

Take component of speed perpendicular to $OB$ and $r=OB$